# SSIS: Package is missing from proj file

Tags: ssis

I'm making a new SSIS package for a project. I click "New Package" and new package file under the project is made with default name Package1.dtsx. The .dtproj project file is updated to include this package. Then I rename the package to the name it's supposed to have "Publish_File.dtsx" but the .dtproj file doesn't update with this new name. Then it fails at compile time because the package I made isn't in the scope of the project and so doesn't have the project-level connection managers. I can't directly edit the .dtproj file because it doesn't have any information until it's built. Does anyone know how to change the name referenced in the .dtproj file to be my file name instead of Package1.dstx?

Comment: How did you rename your pacakge to "Publish_File" ?

Comment: Right-clicked it and selected 'Rename'